# Separate information of sql call

Tags: php, sql

```
$buq = $db->query("
SELECT u.buddylist, u.uid
FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."users u
WHERE u.uid = 1 
ORDER BY u.buddylist DESC 
LIMIT 1");

while ($bud = $db->fetch_array($buq)) {
  $buddytem.='<p style="font-weight:bold;">'.$bud['buddylist'].'</p>';

}
```

The result in html of this is: "1,2,3,4,5"

How can I separate this "1,2,3,4,5" like this?:

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
```

Comment: [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php) is what you're after but this is a terrible relational database design. You should fix that instead using a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

Comment: if the query is returning 1 row why u loop???limit 1

Comment: Well, it's just plain awful. One should **never** store a list of reference values in a single column.

Comment: Do you think that it needs to replace definitely the buddy system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phil is correct...

If you need to apply any logic to each buddy in the list, use explode() with a foreach

```
while ($bud = $db->fetch_array($buq)) {
    $buds = explode( ',', $bud['buddylist'] );
    foreach( $buds as $buditem ) {
        $buddytem.='<p style="font-weight:bold;">'.$buditem.'</p>';
    }
}
```

If you only want to print them out wrapped in tags, don't waste the foreach

```
$prefix = '<p style="font-weight:bold;">';
while ($bud = $db->fetch_array($buq)) {
    $buds = explode( ',', $bud['buddylist'] );
    $buddytem.=$prefix . implode( '</p>' . $prefix, $buditem ) . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot James just what I need, The first code helped me.

Comment: There is a problem with the list it sends

#1 Post number one buddylist: {$numbers1}
#2 Post number two buddylist: {$numbers1}{$numbers2}
and thats the same for all.

how can I stop this like this:
#1 Post number one buddylist: {$numbers1}
#2 Post number two buddylist: {$numbers2}

Answer (score 1):

First of all the way your database is set up is...well not good. Create a separate table to track a person's buddies like:

```
create table buddy_list(id int primary key auto_increment,user int,buddy int);
```

when you want to add a new user to the person's buddy list you can use

```
$query="insert into buddy_list(user,buddy) values('$user','$buddy')";
```

when you want to retrieve a person's buddy list

```
$query="select buddy from buddy_list where user='$user' order by desc";
```

then in your page to display

```
while ($bud = $db->fetch_array($buq)) {
  $buddytem.='<p style="font-weight:bold;">'.$bud['buddy'].'</p>'.'</br>';
}
```

Comment: oh great ksealey I will replace the old buddy system of mybb with this idea thanks a lot seriously !